# tensorflow-magenta bazel error running first test

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, magenta

I have installed the C++ protobuf library on Ubuntu 15.10. When I run the first magenta test within the magenta workspace directory I get this error (changed url to protobuf, cant post not enough reputation points. What a great problem reporting system this is):

root@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/home/ubuntu/magenta# bazel test magenta/...
..
ERROR: package contains errors: magenta.
ERROR: error loading package 'magenta': Encountered error while reading extension file 'protobuf.bzl': no such package '@protobuf//': Error cloning repository: protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.305s
ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run tests.